# python regular expression greedy capture

Tags: python, regex

I need to replace the entire text between AAA and BBB (not including those) in the following multi-line text with a blank.
I tried this pattern => 'This form.*[^Accuracy.]Accuracy.'
But it only captures until first 'Accuracy.'
I tried to do a greedy capture but cannot get the right pattern.
Please help.

```
import re
haystack='''Other needs and/or restrictions:
Telephone visit on 11/16 @ 3:50 PM 
AAA This form has been electronically signed. 
Check for Accuracy. XXX authorized by Dr Zhivago (M.D.) 
This form contains your private health information that 
you may choose to release to another party; 
please review for Accuracy. 
BBB
'''
pattern = 'This form.*[^Accuracy\.]Accuracy\.'
p = re.compile(pattern, re.MULTILINE)
match = p.search(haystack)
if match != None:
    haystack = re.sub(pattern,'',haystack,re.MULTILINE)
    print(haystack)
```

Comment: `.*` is greedy already. Just remove the wholly unnecessary `[^Accuracy\.]` from your pattern.

Comment: The pattern looks for 'AAA', followed by any characters including newlines (.*?), up until the first 'BBB'.
`pattern = '(?<=AAA).*?(?=BBB)'`

Comment: Probably review the [Stack Overflow `regex` tag info page](/tags/regex/info) which explains this common beginner error in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Here is to capture all the strings between AAA and BBB:

```
import re

text = '''Other needs and/or restrictions:
Telephone visit on 11/16 @ 3:50 PM 
AAA This form has been electronically signed. 
Check for Accuracy. XXX authorized by Dr Zhivago (M.D.) 
This form contains your private health information that 
you may choose to release to another party; 
please review for Accuracy. 
BBB'''

pattern = re.compile(r'AAA(.*?)BBB', re.DOTALL)
matches = pattern.findall(text)

for match in matches:
    print(match.strip())
```

Comment: This helped. Thanks